# calculate consecutive TRUE values and display in seperate column as count of TRUE values in squence order

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Sample Data from table in snowflake:

```
| EMAIL | Date |  EmailClicked|
| -------- | -------------- | -------- |
| abc@gmail.com| 01-01-2021| TRUE |
| abc@gmail.com| 02-01-2021| FALSE|
| def@gmail.com| 02-01-2021| FALSE|
| abc@gmail.com| 03-01-2021| TRUE |
| abc@gmail.com| 04-01-2021| TRUE |
| abc@gmail.com| 05-01-2021| TRUE |
| def@gmail.com| 03-01-2021| TRUE|
| def@gmail.com| 06-01-2021| FALSE|
| abc@gmail.com| 06-01-2021| FALSE|
| abc@gmail.com| 07-01-2021| TRUE |
| abc@gmail.com| 08-01-2021| TRUE |
```

Output Expected to display consecutive True Values as another column

```
| EMAIL | Date |  EmailClicked| Consecutivecount |
| -------- | -------------- | -------- | -------- |
| abc@gmail.com| 01-01-2021| TRUE | 1 |
| abc@gmail.com| 02-01-2021| FALSE| 0 |
| abc@gmail.com| 03-01-2021| TRUE | 1 |
| abc@gmail.com| 04-01-2021| TRUE | 2 |
| abc@gmail.com| 05-01-2021| TRUE | 3 |
| abc@gmail.com| 06-01-2021| FALSE| 0 |
| abc@gmail.com| 07-01-2021| TRUE | 1 |
| abc@gmail.com| 08-01-2021| TRUE | 2 |
| def@gmail.com| 02-01-2021| FALSE| 0 |
| def@gmail.com| 03-01-2021| TRUE| 1 |
| def@gmail.com| 06-01-2021| FALSE| 0 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one method uses the difference in row numbers approach:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL, EmailClicked ORDER BY Date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT EMAIL, Date, EmailClicked,
       EmailClicked::int * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL, EmailClicked, rn1-rn2
                                    ORDER BY Date) AS Consecutivecount
FROM cte
ORDER BY EMAIL, Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Nice one! Learned something new

Comment: Thanks Tim for helping with the problem ...!